# How to fix low select2 display

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

how to custom override _attachCloseHandler[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlAvG.png)

because click select show slow
Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of ways that you could go about this:

1. Edit the min.js (assuming that you have downloaded the file and have access to it during development)
2. Place your js below whatever script is making a request to gather this source, scripts are synchronous, and directly modify s.prototype._attachCloseHandler. This is assuming that s is a global value that you can modify.

Comment: I mean, how can I customize and declare to manipulate that function? I tried it this way but it didn't work.

$.fn.select2.amd.define("CustomSelectionAdapter",
    [
        "select2/utils",
    ],
 function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var n = this;
  e.bind = function (e){
   e.on("open", function() {
    console.log('123');
    n.$selection.attr("aria-expanded", "true"),
    n.$selection.attr("aria-owns", i),
    n._attachCloseHandler(e)
   })
  }
 }
);
$("select").select2({
 dataAdapter:$.fn.select2.amd.require("CustomSelectionAdapter")
});